# Javascript split large string into small parts with quotes and line feeds

Tags: javascript

I'm wanting to know a good way of splitting strings into smaller parts and adding quotes and new lines around each line.

I'm looking for something like:

```
'daduiisdaduimasgdas_dasdasjk\n'+
'dyakdonateopelekdoeoicnshals\n' +
'uuuqoqjskeudududududhsdddisd\n' +
'eyruyweuqesda\n'
```

I have tried to use a regex with a join but having no luck `"1234567890".match(/.{1,8}/g).join('\n');`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I didn't understand your question.

Comment: HI nafeo, which part of the question do you not understand?

Comment: What is your given string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `.map` on the array of matched strings first to add quotes, then join:

```js
console.log(
  "1234567890"
    .match(/.{1,8}/g)
    .map(line => `"${line}\\n"`)
    .join('+ \n')
);
```

Comment: its pretty close but I was hoping to have each line like 'eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1Ni\n' + 'eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1Ni\n'

Comment: Do you mean you want a literal `+` in addition to the quotes and newlines?

Comment: I need the new lines and the plus added to each line

Comment: How do I add the \n before the quote at the end of each line?

Comment: Do you mean you want a literal backslash and a literal `n`, in addition to a literal newline? Please edit your question to make it clear what exactly you're looking for

Comment: its very subtle in the question, sorry I'm a complete noob. 'eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1Ni\n' just before the last quote I have put \n'

Comment: Do you mean a literal newline, or a literal backslash followed by a literal `n`? Again, please edit the question to clarify

Comment: I've tried to edit the question, essentially at the end of each string and before the quote I'm wanting a \n as part of that substring

Comment: Again, is that a literal backslash followed by a literal `n`, or a literal newline?

Comment: yes its literal backslash followed by an n. sorry for the hassle

Comment: Ok, see edit, add another backslash so the backslash is interpreted as a literal backslash instead of an escape character

Comment: The second code sample that you posted was closer to what I was looking for "12345678\n" +
"90" if I add the backslash and n to the string heres how it looks

Comment: Again, please edit your question to state **exactly** what you want - Stack Overflow is not supposed to have this sort of extended back-and-forth in comments due to an unclear question. Please fix the question to make it clear what **exactly** you're looking for

Comment: Hi sorry for the hassle, I have made the adjustment and highlighted the output

Comment: Do you mean that you want a literal backslash and a literal `n`, *in addition* to a newline? Or just the literal backslash and literal `n`? Or a newline only?

Comment: Literal backslash and n in addition to a newline